# actions/checkout@v4 still using default path for code checkout when Github action job is run on a container with working directory set

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I have the following GA -

```
name: 'Test'
on:
  workflow_dispatch:


jobs:

  test_artf_image_dir:
    runs-on: my-runner
    container:
      image: my-image:latest

    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: /app

    steps:
      - name: PWD
        id: PWD
        run: |
          pwd # this gives /app
          
      - name: Checkout code
        id: checkout_code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: main
          fetch-depth: 0

          
      - name: show_files
        id: show_files
        run: |
          ls # only shows my docker image directories and not checkout files of demo-repo
          pwd # this gives /app
```

As you can see above `working-directory` is set so that directories inside docker image is available in the action, but when I run **checkout@v4** in this, it is still using default directory to checkout the code and then it is not available in `show_files` step.

```
Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /__w/demo-repo/demo-repo
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings

```
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: /app
```

applies only to `run` steps and they do not impact checkout step at all.

Please check also this github [issue](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25742#discussioncomment-4803666)